# Handling errors, infinite loops

Tags: c, string, error-handling

This creates a mario-like pyramid when the height is entered.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  int height;
  char signal = 'n';

  while (signal != 'y')
  {
    printf("Height: ");
    scanf("%d", &height);

    if (height <= 0)
    {
      printf("Error. Positive #s only. \n");
    }
    else if (height > 23)
    {
      printf("Error. # must be from 0-23. \n");
    }
    else if (height > 0 || height <= 23)
    {
      signal = 'y';
    }
    else
    {
      printf("Can you bulid a pyramid with letters? I thought so... \n");
    }
  }

  int i, j, k;

  for (i = 1; i <= height; i++)
  {
    if (height <= 8)
      printf("\t");
    else if (height <= 16)
      printf("\t\t");
    else if (height <= 23)
      printf("\t\t\t");

    for (k = 0; k < i; k++)
    {
      printf("\b");
    }

    for (j = 0; j <= i; j++)
    {
      printf("#");
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
}
```

If a user decides to be silly and enters a string, the program goes into an infinite loop. I thought the program would use the else statement but doesn't. How do I handle this?

Comment: Please edit your post and fix the indention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check the return value of `scanf`, which returns the number of input items matched and assigned.  If you enter text, it doesn't match anything and the text is left in the input buffer.  So `scanf` keeps trying to read the same non-matching data on each iteration of the loop.

By checking the return value, you can tell whether or not a string was entered.  You'll also need to flush out the input buffer by calling `getchar` until you get a newline.

Try this instead:

```
  int items = scanf("%d", &height);

  if (items < 1) {
      int ch;
      printf("Please enter a number\n");
      while (((ch=getchar()) != '\n') && (ch != EOF));
  else if(height <= 0)
  ...
```

Comment: Ideally, the getchar() loop should also check for EOF, or it runs the risk of running indefinitely.

Comment: @Medinoc Good call.  Edited.

Answer (score 2):

`scanf()` returns a value indicating how many values were successfully read. If it is zero, it means nothing could be read. You should use this value to check for errors in input.